# Vetmedin eaten by wrong dog

Tags: dogs, health, medicines

Lilly takes vetmedin for congestive heart failure. Baxter May have eaten her dose when I dropped it between  them. 2.5 mg for 20# Jack Russell. Help. I don’t know if Lilly got her medicine. Should I give her a half just to make sure she gets some or just skip it?

Comment: For medical emergencies please **always ask your vet** and don't wait for strangers on the internet to maybe give you an answer.

Comment: Should your vet not be available search for an emergency clinic in your country; you can nearly always call them and ask.

Answer (score 1):

My dog may or may not have recieved her congestive heart failure medication.

> **Take her to the vet**.

I cannot stress this enough. In-fact if your other dog does not have CHF I would consider taking them to the vet too if you're unsure what the side effects are for a healthy dog.

In future I would recommend feeding the two dogs further apart so if the medicine is dropped you have more chance of picking up the medicine before either dog consumes it.

If this comes across as a bit sharp I do apologise but this is a serious matter which should definitely be discussed with your vet.